# regex - and . _

Tags: regex

Writing a regex for a-z, A-Z and allowing - and . _ and integers.

For example:

- Testing-Server1
- Testing.Server
- Testing_Server

  Tried this, but was unsure how to allow - _ .  and integers:

  "^[a-z][A-Z]*$"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple enough:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]*$
```

#### Explanation

- `^` = Match from the start of the input
- `[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]` = A character class (a list of allowed characters):

  `-` matches the literal '-' character (must be the first or last character in the class)

  `a-z` matches lowercase alpha characters

  `A-Z` matches uppercase alpha characters

  `0-9` matches the numeric characters

  `_` matches the literal '_' character

  `.` matches the literal '.' character (unlike outside a character class, where it matches *any* character)
- `*` = Match 0 to infinite characters (use `+` to match *at least* one character)
- `$` = Match to the end of the string

#### Alternative

As stranac mentions in his answer, you can replace `a-zA-Z0-9_` with `\w`, but I prefer the more explicit version, as it's more understandable.

#### Limiting matched characters

As the OP asked in a comment, to limit the allowed number of characters to 15:

```
^[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]{0,15}$
```

Where `{0,15}` means match between 0 and 15 characters (of the character class) only.  You can adjust the values as appropriate, for example, to match at least one character, use `{1,15}`.

Comment: If you want to limit maximum string to for example 15 characters ? how could that be done ?

Comment: Thanks, for clarifying it, and making it understandble.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers are over-complicating things.
`\w` already matches letters, digits and underscores, so you only need to add dot and minus to those.

This regex does the trick: `r'^[\w.-]+$'`

A few examples:

```
>>> re.search(r'^[\w.-]+$', 'Testing-Server1').group()
'Testing-Server1'
>>> re.search(r'^[\w.-]+$', 'Testing.Server').group()
'Testing.Server'
>>> re.search(r'^[\w.-]+$', 'Testing_Server').group()
'Testing_Server'
```

Comment: If anyone wonders why the dot doesn't need escaping, it's explained in the [docs for the `re` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).  

`Special characters lose their special meaning inside sets. For example, [(+*)] will match any of the literal characters '(', '+', '*', or ')'.`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of parsing all the string to check if it contains only allowed characters, it is faster to search the first character that is not an allowed character, because the search stops once it is found:

```
if not re.search(r'[^\w.-]', yourstring):
    ...
```

If you need to check the max length of the string, you can simply write:

```
if (len(yourstring) < 16 and not re.search(r'[^\w.-]', yourstring)):
```

Comment: I agree with the thought process, but the correct syntax is `if not re.search(...):`

Comment: That is a better approach to the original problem, but won't fit with the extra requirements the OP has added (match up to 15 characters only).

Answer (score 1):

This following pattern is enough

```
^[a-zA-z1-9._-]+$
```

**Explanation**

- a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
- A-z a single character in the range between A and z (case sensitive)
- 1-9 a single character in the range between 1 and 9
- . matches the character . literally
- the literal character -

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU2rE7/1)

Comment: You don't need to escape dot within `[]`

Answer (score 0):

Try this out :

```
([a-zA-z0-9._-]+)
```

**Explanation:**

***1)*** `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)

***2)*** `A-z` a single character in the range between A and z (case sensitive)

***3)*** `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9

***4)*** `._-` a single character in the list ._- literally

It should work , check this :https://regex101.com/r/gZ5xN5/2

Comment: Why is it allowing: "test\server" ? (The backslash)

Comment: You do not need to escape the `\ ` in a character class. This allows a literal '\' character

Comment: @MohitBhasi sorry Jamie is right you don't need escape inside `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following pattern :

```
[a-zA-Z\d._-]+
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tY7oI3/1)

Comment: That one is allowing space, for exame: All of them.

Comment: @user3270211 sorry i dont get what youmean!!

Comment: It shouldnt allow space between text.

Comment: @user3270211 this doesn't match the space but the first part will be match !

Comment: @user3270211 can you edit your question and clarify that what you want exactly?